# Pig Latin: using field in one table as position value to access data in another table

Tags: apache-pig

Let's say we have two tables. The first table has following description:

animal_count: {zoo_name:chararray, counts:()}

The meaning of "zoo_name" fields is obvious. "counts" fields contains counts of each specific animal species. In order to know what exact species a given field in "counts" tuple represents, we use another table:

species_position : {species:chararray, position:int}

Let assume we have following data in "species_position" table:
"tiger", 0
"elephant", 1
"lion", 2

This data means the first field in animal_count.counts is the number of tigers in a given zoo. The second field in that tuple is the number of elephants, and so on. So, if we want to represent that fact that "san diego zoo" has 2 tigers, 4 elephants and no lion, we will have following data in "animal_count" table:
"san diego zoo", (2, 4, 0)

Given this setup, how can I write a query to extract the number of a given species in all zoos? I was hoping for something like:

FOREACH species_position GENERATE species, animal_count.counts.$position;

Of course, the "animal_count.counts.$position" won't work.

Is this possible without resorting to UDF?

Comment: Is the animal count file stored like 'San Dieago Zoo|2,4,0'? When you say `{zoo_name:chararray, counts:()}` it reads like counts is a tuple of fields rather than a single field.

Comment: Matthew, your interpretation is correct. "counts" is a tuple of fields.

Comment: I gave it a shot and couldn't do it in PigLatin; but UDFs are your friend! Don't be shy about them. Would you be willing to take a UDF as an answer or are you too unfamiliar with them at this point? On the other hand, SO is a bit barren when it comes to Pig latin questions. You may perhaps want to tag this post with `hadoop` `cloudera` `mapr` and `piglatin` or post it on another forum if you don't get an answer soon.

Comment: Matthew, I will take UDF as an answer. I have reached that conclusion myself after googling around for half a day.